# Http persistent connection and switching from wi-fi to cellular on Android

Tags: android, linux, http, networking, tcp

I'm seeing some strange behavior/errors that seem to only occur when switching from wi-fi to cellular.  One of them is the following exception:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket is not connected at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native
>   Method) at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:131)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:247)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:535)
>   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1071) at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:62)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
>   at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1150)
>   at
>   com.nexage.android.reports2.AdReport2$ReportTask.run(AdReport2.java:492)
>   at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:290)

Could this be caused by a persistent connection that somehow got "stuck"?  If so, is there any way to reset the connection?  I know HTTP is supposed to be stateless, and I don't know of any way to "reset" an HTTP connection, but I think there could be some bug at the OS level that is trying to keep it open even though the connection was broken.

Thanks, I've been trying to solve this problem for a week and don't have any clue yet!

Answer (score 0):

Do you detect the network switch and re-establish the HTTP session? Your HTTP/TCP connection will be closed when you switch type of network, causing an error similar to what you see when you try to use it again.

Btw, a persistent HTTP connection does not mean it will be persistent when you disconnect from the network. What it means is that you are, in most cases, allowed to send more than one request over the same connection.